# MainActivity does not exist error in Android react-native

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, react-native

So I'm getting the MainActivity does not exist error, it might be because I renamed the package and app from `bomber` to `Bomber` and changed the appId from `com.bomber` to `cool.bomber.android`

I've checked the AndroidManifest, the activity source files and the build.gradle file but I can't seem to find what's the mistake

Error message

```
Starting: Intent { cmp=cool.bomber.android/.MainActivity }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {cool.bomber.android/cool.bomber.android.MainActivity} does not exist.
```

app/build.gradle

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "cool.bomber.android"
...
```

AndroidMaifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="16"
    android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

<application
  android:name=".MainApplication"
  android:allowBackup="true"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
  <activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        <category android:name="com.google.intent.category.CARDBOARD" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <data android:host="foo.app.goo.gl" android:scheme="http"/>
        <data android:host="foo.app.goo.gl" android:scheme="https"/>
    </intent-filter>
  </activity>
  <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
</application>
```

android/app/src/main/java/cool/bomber/android/MainActivity.java

```
package cool.bomber.android;    
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;

public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {
    @Override
    protected String getMainComponentName() {
        return "Bomber";
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what else I should be looking at to debug.

Comment: did you find the solution to this?

Answer (score 9):

You need to uninstall the application properly.

If it does not work from the phone, you can use cmd

`adb uninstall "package name"`

Comment: This worked for me. Thank you!

Comment: This worked for me. I was getting the error after I added my own custom Android module to my react native packages. I would have never guessed to do this on my own, thanks!

Comment: Cool it worked for me. Even though the app was installed from the device - the error was constant. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Add package name in manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="cool.bomber.android">
```

and still not working than write full package name like this

```
<application
  android:name="cool.bomber.android.MainApplication"
  android:allowBackup="true" >

<activity
    android:name="cool.bomber.android.MainActivity"
    >
```

and make sure this is the right path

and in CMD write this:

```
 cd android & gradlew clean 
      or maybe
 cd android && ./gradlew clean
```

and than run `react-native run-android`

Make sure when you write this code you are at root of your project folder

Or Else:

Follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804093/android-studio-rename-package) to refresh whole project after changing package using android studio.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was that I had added **tools:node="replace"** to my android/app/src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" tools:targetApi="28" tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning" tools:node="replace"/>
```

I had added that based on someone recommending it for some other issue and it caused the infamous Error type 3 to appear.  Once I got rid of it, the problem went away:

```
<application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" tools:targetApi="28" tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning"/>
```

Cheers,
Alvaro

Answer (score 0):

I had to reinstall the app for the problem to be resolved