# react-native app crashing android 13 but fine on android 11

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-cli

Here is the issue on android studio .

```
Error while executing: am start -n "package.name.of.my.app.callerid_test/package.name.of.my.app.callerid.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=ppackage.name.of.my.app.callerid_test/package.name.of.my.app.callerid.MainActivity }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {package.name.of.my.app.callerid_test/package.name.of.my.app.callerid.MainActivity} does not exist.

Error while Launching activity
Failed to launch an application on all devices
```

Comment: it's possible that there is an issue with the version of React Native that you are using. Make sure you are using a version of React Native that is compatible with Android 13.

Comment: @UsamaAltaf it running fine on android 11 and android 13 emulator but crashing on android 13

Comment: see this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49577227/mainactivity-does-not-exist-error-in-android-react-native